# express - create multiple app.get routes in a for-loop

Tags: express

I would like to import routes from an json file and loop through to get an dynamic pdf-manual links. I don't want to hardcode it. Its linkin the file with thr url:

```
const express = require ('express');
const app = express ();

const manuals = require ('./manuals/manuals_links.json');

for (element in manuals.list) {
  console.log (manuals.list[element]);
  app.get (manuals.list[element].permaLink, function (req, res) {
    res.download (manuals.list[element].file);
  });
}
```

The first route links to the correct file, but the second, third and sometimes fourth routes (which do work) will link to the first file and the other routes will not be created. Creating the routes manually allworks fine, so there are no broken links. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tested it and found that is a mistake in your for statement

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const manuals = require("./manuals_links.json");

for (let element in manuals.list) {
  app.get(manuals.list[element].permaLink, function (req, res) {
    console.log(manuals.list[element].file);
    res.download(manuals.list[element].file);
  });
}

const app_server = http.createServer(app);
app_server.listen(5002, () => {
  console.log("app_server started on port", 5002);
});
```

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "permaLink": "/first",
      "file": "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf?r=1"
    },
    {
      "permaLink": "/second",
      "file": "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf?r=2"
    },
    {
      "permaLink": "/third",
      "file": "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf?r=3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue you're facing is due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, combined with the closure scope of the for loop. By the time the app.get callback functions are executed, the loop has already completed, and the value of element is the last value in the loop for all iterations.

To fix this, you can use the let keyword instead of var when declaring the loop variable element. This will create a new lexical scope for each iteration of the loop, ensuring that each callback function captures the correct value of element. Here's an updated version of your code:

By using let instead of var, the value of element will be preserved for each iteration, and each callback function will correctly reference the corresponding element value.

Make sure to restart your server after making this change for it to take effect.

Comment: Works a lot better now, as it has at least now the correct file to the link. But after 3-4 routes no routes will be created anymore, as its stopping to loop. Thanks for checking!

Comment: can you save you manuals_links there https://jsoneditoronline.org/# and send it to me, there can be an error in a object key. If the routes stop being created after a few iterations, it could be due to an error in the JSON file or the structure of the manuals_links.json file. Please ensure that the JSON file is valid and follows the expected structure.

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.2c913110eec049f1986e610e61464968
it seems to stop after the third iteration. Webserver is running, all works good.

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.e3fdd2bf732445a0969f14d0d27c3334 ,you have an error  "permaLink": "9910_Operation_Manual_STANDPOWER_PP_EN" must be  "permaLink": "/9910_Operation_Manual_STANDPOWER_PP_EN"

Comment: Oh!, the JSON was valid but the string was wrong. Thanks!! You solved two problems! :-)